# How to write a column of consecutive integers in Vim over existing text?

Tags: vim

For example, imagine I had the following text:

```
/ apple
/ orange
/ banana
/ bread
```

How could I efficiently add consecutive integers in a column to make?

```
/1 apple
/2 orange
/3 banana
/4 bread
```

Note that in real problems, the list might be 20, 50, or more lines long.

Answer (score 6):

One idea is to use `vim`'s macro feature.  Position the cursor on the first `/` in `/ apple`, and do:

```
a1<Esc>
```

to insert the first number to start everything off (`<Esc>` being the escape key). Then with your cursor on the newly inserted `1`, record the macro (into slot `q`):

```
qqyiwj0p<C-a>q
```

Now you should have the first 2 lines numbered.  You now can run the macro `n-2` times, where `n` is the total number of lines you have.  As an example, if you had 50 lines, we run the macro 48 times since we already filled in 2 lines manually:

```
48@q
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "pipe through an external command" feature that vim has.  Open the file in vim, then do this:

```
:%!cat -n | awk '{print $2, $1, $3;}' | sed 's/ //'
```

You could probably dispense with the sed (which just deletes the first space in each line) by clever awk code.  I just couldn't get it to work in 30 seconds, so I slopped out with sed.

Comment: Personally, I'd be inclined to just pipe it through `cat -n` and do the rest with visual block mode.

Comment: Or pipe through `nl`, which allows the number format to be fine-tuned.